# how many iterations would there be through a double sum?

Tags: summation

$\sum^{100}_{i=1}\sum_{j \neq i} A_iB_j$

How many total summations would happen within this expression?
I'm thinking 100*99? Since there are 100 on the outer sum, and then one less on the inner sum?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you're correct.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks!